# Multi-threading not moving objects at the same time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, object, picturebox

I'm trying to get a thread to move two Picture Boxes at the same time but that doesn't happen, the first one starts moving then when that is done the second one starts. I don't know how to make them move at the same time.

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
Private picuser As New PictureBox()
Private y As Integer
Private thread1 As Thread
Private thread2 As Thread
Private thread3 As Thread
Private thread4 As Thread

Public Sub enemy1()
    picUser = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    picUser.Visible = True
    picUser.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 32)
    picuser.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(100, 100)
    picuser.BackColor = Color.Purple
    Dim e As New AddControlEventArgs(picuser)

    ' Create EventHandler
    Dim ehnd As New EventHandler(AddressOf AddControl)

    ' Invoke EventHandler with EventArgs (don't need sender as of now)
    thread1 = New Thread(Sub() Me.Invoke(ehnd, Nothing, e))
    thread1.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub enemy2()
    picuser = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    picuser.Visible = True
    picuser.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 32)
    picuser.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(150, 100)
    picuser.BackColor = Color.Red
    Dim e As New AddControlEventArgs(picuser)

    ' Create EventHandler
    Dim ehnd As New EventHandler(AddressOf AddControl)

    ' Invoke EventHandler with EventArgs (don't need sender as of now)
    thread2 = New Thread(Sub() Me.Invoke(ehnd, Nothing, e))
    thread2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread3 = New Thread(AddressOf enemy1)
    thread4 = New Thread(AddressOf enemy2)
    thread3.Start()
    thread4.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub mover(ByVal x As PictureBox)
    For z = 0 To 10
        x.Location = New Point(x.Location.X, x.Location.Y + 10)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Me.Refresh()
    Next
End Sub


Public Class AddControlEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
    Public Sub New(p_control As Control)
        m_control = p_control
    End Sub
    Private m_control As Control
    Public ReadOnly Property Control As Control
        Get
            Return m_control
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Private Sub AddControl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Cast EventArgs to your custom EventArgs
    Dim ec As AddControlEventArgs = DirectCast(e, AddControlEventArgs)
    Me.Controls.Add(ec.Control)
    Call mover(ec.Control)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you think `Invoke()` does? You aren't actually doing anything on your threads.  Instead, use a WinForms timer or `Await`.

Comment: I edited the code to use `Await` and it still does exactly the same as I described @SLaks

Comment: No; get rid of the threads entirely and use `Await Task.Delay()`

Answer (score 2):

Use multithreading in a game only if you have heavy calculations to perform, that you want to distribute on the different CPU cores. Otherwise just use a **game loop**. Calculate the actual state of the game and positions of the objects depending on the current game time. Then update the UI and repeat these two steps until the user stops the game.

Using multithreading in order to update the UI won't work, since only one thread at a time can access the UI. To be more precise, only the UI thread (the thread the application is started in) can do it. Therefore the other threads have to call `Invoke` in order to let the UI thread update the UI.

Complicated calculations like artificial intelligence and physical simulations might still require multithreading. Here I see two possibilities:

1. The game loop starts several threads at each game loop and waits until they are all finished and then goes on with updating the UI.
2. The threads run independently and update the game status continuously. The game loop repeatedly reads the game status and updates the UI accordingly. Here you need to lock the game status (the common resource) when accessing it. Keep the lock times short, i.e. do a substantial amount of work, then lock, update, unlock and go on with the calculation. It is probably a good idea to split the game status into several logical parts that can be locked individually. This reduces the chances of lock conflicts. All threads that have to access several resources must access them in the same order. This helps avoiding dead locks.